# Why does this trigger cause a deadlock?

Tags: sql-server

Given this setup.

```
DROP TABLE T1;

CREATE TABLE T1
(RECNUM INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
WHO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DT DATETIME2 NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
CONSTRAINT T1_PK_ID  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T1_TR_AI]                     ON [dbo].[T1]           
AFTER INSERT                                                        
AS                                                                  
BEGIN                                                                   
SET NOCOUNT ON;                                                     
UPDATE A                                                            
SET A.ID = B.RECNUM                             
FROM T1 A                                           
INNER JOIN inserted B ON (A.RECNUM = B.RECNUM)                  
END;        
GO
```

And then running these two scripts from two different instances of SSMS on my workstation (Note Sql instance is on my workstation too)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO T1 (ID,WHO) VALUES (0,'A')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO 50000

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO T1 (ID,WHO) VALUES (0,'B')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO 50000
```

How do I get deadlocks like this?

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process4835828" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process4835828" taskpriority="0" logused="144" waitresource="KEY: 13:72057594043695104 (78d82fa561ac)" waittime="3135" ownerId="1466503" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.080" XDES="0x2db10f0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="5" kpid="12496" status="suspended" spid="63" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.080" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.080" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.080" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="W1643558" hostpid="11600" loginname="WHQ_NT_DOMAIN\KH027556" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1466503" currentdb="13" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="50" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x02000000f18dec12c7d493965de43d9ee9f3ec2f8011251800000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="38" stmtend="112" sqlhandle="0x020000001fafbb0e5b05c5ef76c1ba0a063e1165cb71b82c00000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO T1 (ID,WHO) VALUES (0,'A')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process484d630" taskpriority="0" logused="272" waitresource="PAGE: 13:1:334 " waittime="3121" ownerId="1466501" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.070" XDES="0x2dbeed0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="19972" status="suspended" spid="62" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.070" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-08T09:14:34.070" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.070" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="W1643558" hostpid="11780" loginname="WHQ_NT_DOMAIN\KH027556" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1466501" currentdb="13" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673319008" clientoption2="390200">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="playground.dbo.T1_TR_AI" line="6" stmtstart="316" stmtend="558" sqlhandle="0x03000d00abe7e85608a7970062a80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE A                                                            
SET A.ID = B.RECNUM                             
FROM T1 A                                           
INNER JOIN inserted B ON (A.RECNUM = B.RECNUM    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="50" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x02000000f18dec12c7d493965de43d9ee9f3ec2f8011251800000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="38" stmtend="112" sqlhandle="0x0200000018ea0a3996f68c35648ac322cee2d05b887ef67f00000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO T1 (ID,WHO) VALUES (0,'B')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594043695104" dbid="13" objectname="playground.dbo.T1" indexname="T1_PK_ID" id="lock1da17580" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043695104">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process484d630" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process4835828" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="334" dbid="13" subresource="FULL" objectname="playground.dbo.T1" id="lock20938f00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594043695104">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process4835828" mode="IX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process484d630" mode="U" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

I also tried this with an Instead of Trigger like;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T1_TR_II] ON [dbo].[T1]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN

   BEGIN TRAN
   INSERT T1
   SELECT ID, WHO, DT
   FROM inserted;

   UPDATE T1
   SET ID=RECNUM
   WHERE RECNUM = @@IDENTITY
   COMMIT TRAN
  END
```

Still encountered deadlocks.  Doesn't the insert and trigger happened as one transaction, or at least a nested transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to update `T1` at the same time as inserting into `T1` on another thread.

The insert statement in both transactions needs to take an exclusive lock on the table and hold it for the duration of the transaction (`i.e. TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK`), so that once they have the lock, they can also freely update the table following the insert, without deadlocking with the other transaction trying to do the same thing.

Comment: So the first client gets a lock on T1 for the insert, doesn't the AFTER INSERT trigger happen within that transaction too, nested under the original INSERT transaction?

Comment: @Kurt, it's a common misconception that transactions are synonymous with locks. The transaction assures you that either all changes succeed or none of them do - in the case of a deadlock, none of them do, and the whole thing is rolled back. But by default a transaction will not lock the entire table (and it does not automatically hold locks taken through the entire transaction, unless you specify `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level). That's basically how deadlocks happen, when two transactions each take a lock on something, and then each try to take a lock on something that the other has already.

Comment: and the reason I see deadlocks with the INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger as shown above is that a lock on T1 happens when the INSERT statement is encountered, regardless of the fact that the actual insert takes place in a transaction in the trigger?

Comment: @Kurt, it's not quite that simple as there are different types of locks. In this case, the insert is taking a key lock to protect the new value until the changes are comitted, and both transactions can do this without conflicting with each other, so they proceed. But when they come to the next step, the update, each transaction is trying to take a page lock (which is a lock with more coverage) - neither can now proceed, because the other retains a conflicting key lock on the value it inserted.

Comment: Steve, really appreciate the information.  So we risk deadlocks at high concurrency times.  My other thought was to create a COMPUTED COLUMN, ID AS RECNUM PERSISTED and still make ID my PK.  This would solve my issue of needing ID = RECNUM but can't use SEQUENCES since we support back to SQL 2005.  But that would mean I would have to load a copy of the table with IDENTITY INSERT ON to set RECNUM to the existing ID (since it has related tables), then reload the original table with the computed column.  YES ID is fixed to an IDENTITY COLUMN going forward. Am I crazy?

Comment: @Kurt, no problem at all. Few more points though, is it necessary to have the `RECNUM` column separate but identical to the `ID` column? In general you'd just have one or the other (selecting the second value as an alias of the first if necessary), unless you're supporting legacy code or there is the possibility of the two not being equal. As you say, you can force the `IDENTITY` column to start at an offset if you need to continue a sequence that was began elsewhere. Also, it is indeed possible to code in ways that avoid deadlocks - you don't necessarily have to put up with them.

Comment: yes I can't change the structure of the table with regards to existing columns, so I need both RECNUM and ID.  Yes this is for some legacy code that due to language and middleware constraints, plus resources to go change tons of code/test/deploy/etc, aren't there. Will the persisted ID column (defined as a PK) work the same way as if it were a non computed normal column?  With the exception, I can't change it without also changing RECNUM.  Any performance issues this might cause ?

Comment: @Kurt, ah I see. Yes I believe the computed column should work in this case, and can be made the primary key. Just test that it does work exactly as intended however. I can't foresee any performance issues - it will be far more performant than the trigger.